# A paradox in counting number of 3-digit odd integers having distinct digits

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following two methods for counting number of 3-digit odd integers  $\overline{a_2a_1a_0}$ having *distinct* digits:
Method 1)
we have 5 choices for $a_0$ , 10-1 choices for $a_1$ and 9-1-1 choices for $a_2$ which gives a total count of: $5\times9\times7=315$
Method 2)
we have 5 choices for $a_0$ , 9-1 choices for $a_2$ and 10-1-1 choices for $a_1$ which gives a total count of  $5\times8\times8=320$.
We do know the the correct answer is 320,so what's wrong with first method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $9-1-1$ choices for $a_2$ IF you've chosen $a_1\not=0$. If $a_1=0$, then there are $10-1-1$ choices instead.

Comment: So can you correct the first method to give correct answer???

Comment: The first method is using the multiplication rule incorrectly. The only way to correct it would be to consider whether $a_2=0$ by cases. If so, then there are $5\cdot 1\cdot 8$ odd numbers; if not, then there are $5\cdot 8\cdot 7$ numbers. $5\cdot1\cdot8+5\cdot8\cdot7=40+280=320$ total.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you,but I think you have a mistake in your last comment mentioning $a_2$ instead of $a_1$, don't you?

Comment: Yeah. It's too late to fix it, though.

Comment: Could you please explain why should we consider 2 cases for $a_1$ in first method? Why not doing that makes first method wrong????

Comment: Because the number of choices for $a_2$ depends on what you have done already. That means you cannot use the multiplication method. The only way around that, but still using the multiplication method, is to break it into cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more clear if you consider the order you select. I mean the following :

1. First select $a_0$. It is clear there are 5 choices, namely (1,3,5,7,9)
2. The consider choices for $a_2$. It cannot be $0$ (not 3 digit number) and it cannot be $a_0$ (distinct condition). Thus there are $8$ choices.
3. Finally there are also $8$ choices for $a_1$, since it cannot be $=a_2$ neither $=a_0$.

So the correct answer is $5 \times 8 \times 8 = 320$

Comment: Our main problem is with first method:  If we decide to check $a_1$ before $a_2$,why should we distinguish two cases for $a_1$???

Comment: I don't see two cases for $a_1$. Simply if you have to find all possible choices (for $a_1$) then you have to look at the whole picture. Put it in other words, it is not a paradox, but if you follow the first method it is easy to get tricked.

Comment: Finally I figured it out: If we check possible cases of $a_1$ before $a_2$ then we must consider that when $a_1=0$ there are 8 possible choices for $a_2$ and when $a_1 \neq 0$  there are 7 possible choices for $a_2$!  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out:
If we check possible cases of $a_1$ before $a_2$ then we $must$ consider that when $a_1=0$ there are 8 possible choices for $a_2$ and when $a_1\neq0$ there are 7 possible choices for $a_2$! That's all.